# Too long line in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, languages

I have a problem with the caption displayed in the table of contents being too long and latex doesn't seem to be able to make the right linebreaks. What did I do wrong or how can I manually enter a line break in the TOC?

The problem looks like this (the 202 is the page number):

[image: problematic toc line]

```
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}
[...]

\begin{otherlanguage}{german}
[...]
    \subsubsection{Andreas Steibl (Geschäftsführer, CEO Tourismusverband Paznaun-Ischgl), 17.07.2019}
[...]
\end{otherlanguage}
```

Although the document is English I surrounded the included file (which is German) with the otherlanguage environment as you can see. Does this then automatically apply to the TOC as well?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\appendix
\setcounter{page}{202}
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Subsection} \label{section_habitats}
\subsubsection{Andreas Steibl (Geschäftsführer, CEO Tourismusverband Paznaun-Ischgl), 17.07.2019}
\subsubsection{Christian Zangerle (Bergführer und Skilehrer aus Galtür), 27.07.2019}\subsubsection{Anton \glqq{}Toni\grqq{}  Zangerl (Obmann der Agrargemeinschaft Pardatsch-Idalpe, Landwirt, Skilehrer), 28.07.2019} \label{AntonZangerl}

\end{document}
\setcitestyle{square}
```

Comment: Please extend this sniplet to a full, but minimal, self contained example that others can test as is. As your question sits here, we have no idea what we are working with, what document class, relevant packages etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% tocprob.tex  SE 597023
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}    %%%%
\cftsetrmarg{4em}       %%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\appendix
\setcounter{page}{202}
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Subsection} \label{section_habitats}
\subsubsection{Andreas Steibl (Geschäftsführer, CEO Tourismusverband Paznaun-Ischgl), 17.07.2019}
\subsubsection{Christian Zangerle (Bergführer und Skilehrer aus Galtür), 27.07.2019}
27.07.2019`\subsubsection{Anton \glqq{}Toni\grqq{}  Zangerl (Obmann der Agrargemeinschaft Pardatsch-Idalpe, Landwirt, Skilehrer), 28.07.2019} \label{AntonZangerl}

\end{document}
```

The `\cftsetrmarg{4em}` increases the right margin to `4em` which reduces the space for the titles thus making them break earlier. Note that something like `28.07.2019` cannot be hyphenated.

Comment: Thank you, now some lines don't break but seem to go into the margin but I can live with that, since they don't interfere with the page number